# Iterate over Two Class with constants and load their fields into a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have two java class with constants, For Ex:

```
public class FirstClass {

 public static final String STRING_A = "STRING_A";
 public static final String STRING_B = "STRING_B";
 public static final String STRING_C = "STRING_C";
    ...
}


public class SecondClass {

 public static final String STRING_AA = "STRING_AA";
 public static final String STRING_BA = "STRING_BA";
 public static final String STRING_CA = "STRING_CA";
    ...
}
```

Now, I want to load these constants into a, 
    **Map< String,String> classPropertyMap = new HashMap<>();** in Such a way that, Key for this map must be a constant from FirstClass and corresponding value must be a constant from SecondClass.

If it was just one class I could use reflection to load the fields, now since the constants are from two class, how could this be done?

Finally after loading the map, the contents of the map must be something like this:

First element : key and value is < STRING_A, STRING_AA>

Second element : key and value is < STRING_B, STRING_BA>

Third element : key and value is < STRING_C, STRING_CA>

Comment: You could still use reflection and try to map the fields but the main question is: _why_? What do you want to achieve? What are those constants for in the first place? And what would the map mean?

Comment: The two constants class are : The first contains the properties I have declared, and second one contains the properties from a third party library. I want to have a map so that I keep the properties sync'ed  i.e. up to date of properties.

Comment: It's still hard to get what the actual problem is. But why don't you just use an enum for that where each value contains the mapping of the property names? Or if you don't want to use an enum then why don't you just fill the map manually? The property constants in the 3rd party lib shouldn't change anyways or otherwise you could run into problems with automatic mapping as well.

Comment: How about using an enum with a string field for the first class? You can then call values() to get all the values for the first class. That should get rid of one lot of reflection. If we knew more about what you were doing I suspect that we could find a better solution.

Comment: What is the rule that maps `STRING_A` to `STRING_AA`? Is it the order in class? If so you have no other chance then do the mapping yourself because the order is not guaranteed to stay the same in ByteCode.

Comment: Is there a mapping between the respective names of the attributes in each class? i.e. in every attribute of the first class is a prefix of its corresponding attribute in the second class, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you really need it, the most robust way is to put the properties to a map explicitly.

I mean `map.put(FirstClass.STRING_A, SecondClass.STRING_AA);` and so on.

If you use reflection you rely on the properties and their declaration order never changes. If some new property is introduced in the library, it can break your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below, seems you can achieve.

```
FirstClass first = new FirstClass();
Field[] fields = first.getClass().getFields();

SecondClass second = new SecondClass();
Field[] fields1 = second.getClass().getFields();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
FirstClass first  = new FirstClass();    
String[] firstStrings = first.getStrings();
//Makes a String array, and fills it with the strings from the first class.

SecondClass second  = new SecondClass();    
String[] secondStrings = second.getStrings();    
//Makes a String array, and fills it with the strings from the second class.

HashMap<String, String> classPropertyMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
int i = 0;

//Now put strings with the same index number from both arrays into the 
//HashMap

while(i <= firstStrings.length()){
    classPropertyMap.put(firstStrings.get(i), secondStrings.get(i);
    i++;
}
```

Hope that works!